# How can i create Roles In laravel 5

Tags: roles, laravel-5

I want to make client login and registration; and Admin login in laravel 5.  In my database I gave a column named "roles" with enum 'admin'and 'client'.

Now what should I make in Routes.php and other files if necessary to redirect client to client page and admin to admin area after login successful.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel, try bican/roles. I've been using it for a few weeks and its great!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at something like Sentry.

Available here:
https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/2.1

The syntax is clean, and aligns well to laravel

```
Sentry::createGroup(array(
    'name'        => 'Subscribers',
    'permissions' => array(
        'admin' => 1,
        'users' => 1,
    ),
));
```